# Java creating a 2d int array which getting bigger inside

Tags: java, matrix, 2d

I want to create a 2d int array thats getting bigger from the outside to the inside, the first layer should start with 1 and the next layer should be 1 higher.

With n = 3 it should look like this :

- 1 1 1 1 1 1
- 1 2 2 2 2 1
- 1 2 3 3 2 1
- 1 2 3 3 2 1
- 1 2 2 2 2 1
- 1 1 1 1 1 1

thats what i already have

```
    int n = 3;
    int[][] feld = new int[2*n][2*n];
    int c = 1 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2*n; j++) {
            feld[i][j] = c-i+j;
        }
        c++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < feld.length; i++) { //this to printing the matrix
        for (int j = 0; j < feld[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(feld[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: The question is how I would solve that problem

Comment: What problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
    int n = 3;
    int[][] feld = new int[2*n][2*n];
    int c = 0;

    while(c<n) {
        for(int i = c; i < 2*n-c; i++) {
            feld[c][i] = c+1;
            feld[i][c] = c+1;
            feld[2*n-c-1][i] = c+1;
            feld[i][2*n-c-1] = c+1;
        }
        c++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < feld.length; i++) { //print the matrix
        for (int j = 0; j < feld[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(feld[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

You can change n to whatever value and it should still work